# Order of tabs on home page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way (or plugin) to order tabs on Jenkins home page? By default, they are sorted in alphabetical order.

[Only info I've found is 'no'](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Ordering-of-view-tabs-on-home-page-td363811.html), but it is quite old.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is still true?

Comment: I don't know anything about any change here.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a plugin that lets me sort tabs manually a couple of weeks ago. I didn't find anything. So I'm almost sure the answer is still *no*.

As a workaround we use a prefix like "(0) Viewname A", "(1) Viewname B" etc. in order to have the most important views accessible by one click.

Comment: This is what I do at the minute, although this doesn't allow to order all tabs E.g. 'All' tab and 'Build Radiator' tab delivered by 'Build Monitor Plugin' can't be configured that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a script to Jenkins, this way it will load each time the view is up.
Go to:
Manage Jenkins->Configure System-> URL of theme JS and add the script.
I used the following script:

```
sessionStorage["ts_direction::" + window.location.toString() +"::0"] = "type=string&value=3%3Aup"
```

This order the columns by the 4th column (remember this will affect all of the views!).

example:
[image: column_order]

Comment: This is a good enough solution until something get built into Jenkins. I didn't find any plugins that just did this, it was usually a small feature of a bigger change to the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Nested View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Nested+View+Plugin) (a functional plugin based on the [hudson.model.TreeView class](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-232)) which allows grouping job views into multiple levels instead of one big list of tabs.

Alternatively prefix the names with numbers (e.g. `1-Foo`, `2-Bar`, `3-Baz`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the view name with a [soft hyphen](https://unicode-table.com/en/00AD/) `­` to make them appear at the end or with a space  to make them appear infront  ­

```js
shy = String.fromCharCode(173);
chars = ['A','B','Z', shy + 'Z','a',' a','b','z',];
document.body.innerHTML = chars.toString() + '<br/>' + chars.sort().toString()
```

```html
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```